# Shortcut key to simple textbox to perform Google search

Tags: search, google

#### Question

- What would be a good tool to enable me to press a shortcut key that brings up a simple textbox where I can type some search terms and then press enter to perform a Google search?

#### Additional points

- I know that I can press a shortcut key to start a browser and have Google as my default search engine. This is too slow.
- I have read a little bit about lenses, but they sound like more than what I want.
- Before switching to Ubuntu, on Windows I have used AutoHotKey to trigger a search box. I also really liked [Dave's Quick Search Bar](http://www.dqsd.net/) many years ago when I was on XP.
- Google desktop also sounds like more than what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Since Google Desktop stopped working, I've been forced to look for another solution.
Here's what I've done:

#### Setup

- I installed Guake, a drop down terminal that can be triggered by F12.
- I installed `surfraw`, a command-line search program.
- I wrote a simple script called `g`.

The script looks like this; it's not perfect but it seems to get the job done.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage g search-terms
#
# short command designed to perform a google search from the command-line

surfraw -browser=chromium-browser google  $* 2>/dev/null &
```

#### Using this approach

To do a quick google search I do the following

- F12 to bring up terminal
- `g search term` to perform search
- F12 to hide the terminal

Answer (score 1):

which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you're using 10.10 or earlier (or 11.04 on Ubuntu Classic), then you can install Deskbar into your panel.

Just open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get-install deskbar-applet`

If you're using 11.04 with Unity, then [This link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/web-sources-lens-for-unity-puts-web-search-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/) may help.

Comment: Thanks. Alas, I'm using 11.04 with Unity; I had a quick look at the lens option that you link to, but I don't think it is quite what I'm after. I still like to get my search results from Google in my preferred browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **Google Desktop** using Quick Search Box feature. The search box appears when you press Ctrl key twice. For more info go to http://desktop.google.com/features.html#search

Comment: Thanks. Google Desktop is an option, but I don't want the desktop search features, and from when I tried it years ago, Google Desktop Search does have implications for computer performance with all the indexing it does.

Comment: @jeromy-Anglim: you can stop google desktop from indexing you computer. for details see http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=32897

Comment: +1 I might give disabling desktop search a go. thanks.

Comment: it seems to work well, although I changed the default shortcut key.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems that google desktop isn't being developed anymore; and after upgrading to 11.10 google desktop didn't work for me anymore.